Databricks SQL Will Not Accept Correlated Columns Error: Correlated column is not allowed in a non-equality predicate
I have a T-SQL Query that includes correlated columns. When I attempt to execute the query with Databricks SQL I get the error:
Error in SQL statement: AnalysisException: Correlated column is not allowed in a non-equality predicate:
Aggregate [max(DateOfChange#20975) AS max(DateOfChange)#20988]
+- Filter (((SiiAuditTypeID#20976 = 3) AND (SplitID#20973 = outer(SplitID#20825))) AND outer(StatusID#20829) IN (1,2))
   +- SubqueryAlias sia
      +- SubqueryAlias spark_catalog.dbo.SiiAudit
         +- Relation[SiiAuditID#20972,SplitID#20973,AccountID#20974,DateOfChange#20975,SiiAuditTypeID#20976,UserID#20977,UserName#20978,PortfolioID#20979,PortfolioSplit#20980,SiiAuditEntryKindID#20981,ModelPortfolioID#20982,primary_key_hash#20983,change_key_hash#20984,reject_reason#20985,reject_row#20986] parquet
;
Distinct
+- Project [AccountID#20826, CreatedDate#20827, StatusID#20829, scalar-subquery#20691 [SplitID#20825 && StatusID#20829] AS CancelledDate#20692]
   :  +- Aggregate [max(DateOfChange#20975) AS max(DateOfChange)#20988]
   :     +- Filter (((SiiAuditTypeID#20976 = 3) AND (SplitID#20973 = outer(SplitID#20825))) AND outer(StatusID#20829) IN (1,2))
   :        +- SubqueryAlias sia
   :           +- SubqueryAlias spark_catalog.dbo.SiiAudit

Can someone help refactor the T-SQL such that it executes without correlated/subqueries.
The query is as follows:
SELECT DISTINCT
           s.AccountID,
           s.CreatedDate,
           s.StatusID,
           (
               SELECT MAX(DateOfChange) AS CancelledDate
               FROM CRM.InvestmentInstruction.SiiAudit sia
               WHERE sia.SiiAuditTypeID = 3 -- cancelled
                     AND sia.SplitID = s.SplitID
                     AND s.StatusID IN ( 1, 2 ) -- cancelled, completed
           ) AS CancelledDate
    FROM CRM.InvestmentInstruction.Split s
        INNER JOIN CRM.InvestmentInstruction.SplitPortfolio sp
            ON sp.SplitID = s.SplitID
        INNER JOIN CRM.InvestmentInstruction.InvestmentRequest ir
            ON ir.InvestmentRequestID = sp.InvestmentRequestID
        INNER JOIN CRM.dbo.ModelPortfolio mp
            ON mp.ModelPortfolioID = ir.ModelID
        INNER JOIN
        (
            SELECT DISTINCT
                   mh.ModelPortfolioID
            FROM CRM.dbo.modelHolding mh
                INNER JOIN Securities.dbo.Security sec
                    ON sec.SecurityID = mh.LinkSecurityId
            WHERE sec.IsCashSecurity = 0
        ) mh
            ON mh.ModelPortfolioID = mp.ModelPortfolioID
    WHERE s.TypeID = 0


What happens if you remove and s.StatusID in (1,2)? Does it run? Without sample data and expected output it's tough to ask someone to re-write this so that it runs as you expect.

Hi @Isolated, thanks for getting in touch. Why would I want to remove and s.StatusID in (1,2)

Well, I'm asking because you're referencing table alias 'S', but you don't have that table alias in your sub-query. Just want to know if that's what is causing the error, that's all. It's not a fix, but rather, just a step in troubleshooting.

ok, let me see what happens. However, I think might need the query refactored to work without subquery

To work without Subquery ...

OK, I removed  AND s.StatusID IN ( 1, 2 ) and it worked. However, I'm still not sure why it worked. Bear in mind, I'm not the originator of the code.

That caused the error because that subquery has no idea what "S" is at that point. You could join CRM.InvestmentInstruction.Split s in that subquery as one thought.

Not sure how what joining CRM.InvestmentInstruction.Split s would look like

Can you move the condition outside the subquery this way?:
case when s.StatusID in (1, 2) then (
           SELECT MAX(DateOfChange)
           FROM CRM.InvestmentInstruction.SiiAudit sia
           WHERE sia.SiiAuditTypeID = 3 -- cancelled
                 AND sia.SplitID = s.SplitID) end as CancelledDate


can you show me how to create a CASE statement for the other sub query?

@Patterson Where's the other one? That second select doesn't appear to be correlated.

@Patterson case expression - SQL doesn't have a case statement.
